# ¿Como puedo usar un .append() dentro de un evento select? - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que quiero hacer exactamente es generar unos input dentro de un formulario, y que se generen mediante un select que tendra unos numeros para que el append genere estos input

Aqui dejo el codigo del formulario :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal-Familia">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title"> </h4>
         </div>
         <div class="photo" id="familyimg">
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="tpdoc">Numero de Familiares</label>
                     <div class="selectContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                           <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-num"></i></span>
                           <select class="form-control">
                              <option value=" " disabled selected hidden>nro. Acompañantes</option>
                              <option>1</option>
                              <option>2</option>
                              <option>3</option>
                              <option>4</option>
                              <option>5</option>
                              <option>6</option>
                              <option>7</option>
                              <option>8</option>
                              <option>9</option>
                              <option>10</option>
                           </select>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="tpdoc">Tipo de Documento</label>
                     <div class="selectContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                           <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-dni"></i></span>
                           <select class="form-control">
                              <option value=" " disabled selected hidden>Porfavor escoja un Doc</option>
                              <option value="DNI">DNI</option>
                              <option value="C.Ext.">C.Ext.</option>
                              <option value="Pasaporte">Pasaporte</option>
                           </select>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="doc">Documento</label>
                     <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                           <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-num"></i></span>
                           <input placeholder="Ingrese documento" class="form-control" type="text" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)" maxlength="0">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="doc" >Vencimiento doc</label>
                     <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                           <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-ven"></i></span>
                           <input placeholder="Ingrese Fecha de Vencimiento del Doc." class="form-control inputfecha" type="text" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                     <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                           <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-add"></i></span>
                           <input placeholder="Ingrese Nombres" class="form-control" type="text" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="phone">Apellidos</label>
                     <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                           <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-pen"></i></span>
                           <input placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos" class="form-control" type="text" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Así se ve visualmente :

[image: Este es el Modal donde tengo el formulario y quiero que los inputs extras de pongan debajo del input text "Apellidos"]

Este es el Modal donde tengo el formulario y quiero que los inputs extras de pongan debajo del input text "Apellidos"

y estos son los input que quiero agregar cada vez que se genera con el .append()

```
<div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="tpdoc">Tipo de Documento</label>
                     <div class="selectContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                           <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-dni"></i></span>
                           <select class="form-control">
                              <option value=" " disabled selected hidden>Porfavor escoja un Doc</option>
                              <option value="DNI">DNI</option>
                              <option value="C.Ext.">C.Ext.</option>
                              <option value="Pasaporte">Pasaporte</option>
                           </select>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="doc">Documento</label>
                     <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                           <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-num"></i></span>
                           <input placeholder="Ingrese documento" class="form-control" type="text" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)" maxlength="0">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="doc" >Vencimiento doc</label>
                     <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                           <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-ven"></i></span>
                           <input placeholder="Ingrese Fecha de Vencimiento del Doc." class="form-control inputfecha" type="text" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                     <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                           <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-add"></i></span>
                           <input placeholder="Ingrese Nombres" class="form-control" type="text" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="phone">Apellidos</label>
                     <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                        <div class="input-group">
                           <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-pen"></i></span>
                           <input placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos" class="form-control" type="text" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

Si por A o B se les puede poner un ID independiente a los nuevos input que se van generando o si de alguna manera pueda tomar su valor o su texto con los nth-child para tomarlos con jquery se los agradecería mucho que me lo confirmaran.

Les agradecería que me den un poco de su conocimiento sobre Jquery para hacer esto, les juro que e intentado viendo foros y documentaciones pero no lo e conseguido, muchas gracias a todos que se tomaron la molestia :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega un identificador al **select**

```
<select class="form-control" id="nroAcompanantes">
```

Después al finalizar la fila que contiene el campo *Apellidos* agrega un **div** vacío, así:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="phone">Apellidos</label>
         <div class="inputGroupContainer">
            <div class="input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-pen"></i></span>
               <input placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos" class="form-control" type="text" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="camposDinamicos">
</div>
```

Por último con jQuery obtenemos la cantidad de acompañantes, ese dato nos servirá para dos acciones:

1. Asignarle el **ID="extra' + i + '"** a cada **row**.
2. Definir el número de iteraciones del **FOR**.

El contenido dinámico se asigna a la variable **divRow**, limpiamos con **html()** el contenido antes de hacer cada **append()**.

```
$('#nroAcompanantes').change(function(){
  var nroAcompanantes = $(this).val();
  var divRow = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < nroAcompanantes; i++) {
    divRow += '<div class="row" id="extra' + i + '">';
      divRow +='   <div class="col-md-6">';
      divRow +='      <div class="form-group">';
      divRow +='         <label for="tpdoc">Tipo de Documento</label>';
      divRow +='         <div class="selectContainer">';
      divRow +='            <div class="input-group">';
      divRow +='               <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-dni"></i></span>';
      divRow +='               <select class="form-control">';
      divRow +='                  <option value=" " disabled selected hidden>Porfavor escoja un Doc</option>';
      divRow +='                  <option value="DNI">DNI</option>';
      divRow +='                  <option value="C.Ext.">C.Ext.</option>';
      divRow +='                  <option value="Pasaporte">Pasaporte</option>';
      divRow +='               </select>';
      divRow +='            </div>';
      divRow +='         </div>';
      divRow +='      </div>';
      divRow +='   </div>';
      divRow +='   <div class="col-md-6">';
      divRow +='      <div class="form-group">';
      divRow +='         <label for="doc">Documento</label>';
      divRow +='         <div class="inputGroupContainer">';
      divRow +='            <div class="input-group">';
      divRow +='               <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-num"></i></span>';
      divRow +='               <input placeholder="Ingrese documento" class="form-control" type="text" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)" maxlength="0">';
      divRow +='            </div>';
      divRow +='         </div>';
      divRow +='      </div>';
      divRow +='   </div>';
      divRow +='</div>';
      divRow +='<div class="row">';
      divRow +='   <div class="col-md-6">';
      divRow +='      <div class="form-group">';
      divRow +='         <label for="doc" >Vencimiento doc</label>';
      divRow +='         <div class="inputGroupContainer">';
      divRow +='            <div class="input-group">';
      divRow +='               <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-ven"></i></span>';
      divRow +='               <input placeholder="Ingrese Fecha de Vencimiento del Doc." class="form-control inputfecha" type="text" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)">';
      divRow +='            </div>';
      divRow +='         </div>';
      divRow +='      </div>';
      divRow +='   </div>';
      divRow +='   <div class="col-md-6">';
      divRow +='      <div class="form-group">';
      divRow +='         <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>';
      divRow +='         <div class="inputGroupContainer">';
      divRow +='            <div class="input-group">';
      divRow +='               <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-add"></i></span>';
      divRow +='               <input placeholder="Ingrese Nombres" class="form-control" type="text" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)">';
      divRow +='            </div>';
      divRow +='         </div>';
      divRow +='      </div>';
      divRow +='   </div>';
      divRow +='</div>';
      divRow +='<div class="row">';
      divRow +='   <div class="col-md-6">';
      divRow +='      <div class="form-group">';
      divRow +='         <label for="phone">Apellidos</label>';
      divRow +='         <div class="inputGroupContainer">';
      divRow +='            <div class="input-group">';
      divRow +='               <span class="input-group-addon svg-ico"><i class="icon-pen"></i></span>';
      divRow +='               <input placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos" class="form-control" type="text" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)">';
      divRow +='            </div>';
      divRow +='         </div>';
      divRow +='      </div>';
      divRow +='   </div>';
      divRow +='</div>';
  }
  $('#camposDinamicos').html('');
  $('#camposDinamicos').append(divRow);
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.